# How to securely/non-interruptively remove a device after overwriting partition table with dd?

Tags: usb, mount

After writing to a device it's recommended and possible to "securely remove" the device by unmounting it. That implies to have a parition to unmount which implies to have a partition table managing that partition. After writing e.g. an Ubuntu Live iso with `dd`, on a device the parition layout which was valid during mount is no longer present because overwritten. If the device was never mounted the same issue occurs. I see activity on the USB pendrive I'm writing to for several seconds after `dd` finished which definitely means a change to mess up the write action. How can I make sure that no data writes are pending when I unplug the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As root run the command sync or if a normal user run sudo sync (this will ensure the write cache is flushed and that it is safe to unmount your SD card).

So , after dd command has finished run

```
sudo sync
```

After that you are safe to remove the drive you write to (This flushes anything that remains cached).